# Why we keep .min.js file in VS solution while Optimization BundleCollection will minify them in RunTime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification

As you knew `System.Web.Optimization` will `Minify` `JavaScript` & `CSS` files for `Release` mode in run-time and publishing.

So, Why we keep `.min.js` file in VS solution?

[image]

I know I can remove min files from project but what to know main reason.

Comment: I`m surprised to see nobody answered this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found using the minified version of the library that release by contributor have some benefits:

1. Helps the client browser used the cached library from other sites.
2. ASP.NET Core doesn't have predefined minified on default project.
3. Minifiers faced some problems with big libraries like Bootstrap 4